# bash tab completion is showing commands instead of files and folders

Tags: macos, bash, shell, osx-snow-leopard, autocomplete

I used `chmod` to make some scripts executable, and now my bash shell is tab-autocompleting all available commands.

How can I make it go back to completing just files / folders in the current folder?

Comment: It always tab-autocompletes command names as the first thing after the prompt. Are you saying that even after you enter a command name, it keeps offering command names as the next word of the command line? Are you sure you're not in a directory full of command files?

Comment: ah true! I was trying to access `bin` folder commands. With `bin/` and then tab it works, but it I type `b` and tab it shows a huge list. which makes sense. thanks Spiff

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It always tab-autocompletes command names as the first thing after the prompt. Are you saying that even after you enter a command name, it keeps offering command names as the next word of the command line? Are you sure you're not in a directory full of command files?